# Series of stories about aliens who find humans adorable and cannot say no to us

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can you help me identify the author and name of a series of stories? I'm not sure whether they were short stories or novellas.

It was about humans meeting a more advanced alien race, that by a freak accident of biology finds human beings beautiful and adorable. So much so that they find it almost impossible to say no to us. It winds up corrupting the human race and severely damaging the aliens.

I originally thought it was called The Worthing Saga, but that seems to be a series of books by Orson Scott Card that is unrelated. I believe it was something that sounded a bit like that.

It was poetically tragic, because the aliens are intelligent and self-aware and realize that they're succumbing to their own detriment, but can't help themselves. It was a compelling allegory about codependency and maddening love. I don't think I read all the stories and I want to read more if I can find them. I came across them on the Internet a long time ago.

It wasn't a sexual attraction at all, maybe A Touch of Romance but it was mostly the way some people can go crazy over their cats or kids and spoil them to the harm of both cat and human, but much worse.

Comment: This is like the exact opposite of the Tiptree story "And I Awoke and Found Me Here on the Cold Hill's Side" in which humans are irresistably drawn to aliens.

Comment: There's an element of this in China Mieville's *Embassytown*, although there the aliens are addicted to a human voice.

Comment: Until you specified "no sexual attraction", I was going to guess *Star Trek*.

Comment: Also probably not it, but https://www.geeksaresexy.net/2022/12/30/irresistible-a-short-story-about-the-introduction-of-humanity-to-the-rest-of-the-galaxy/ had humans with irresistible voices. "Unsurprisingly, Morgan Freeman's voice became deemed a weapon of mass destruction."

Answer (score 5):

This pretty much can't be your story, but posting as a partial *[They are Smol](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheyAreSmol)*, a series of stories on the web by Tiny Prancing Horse that originated on [the r/HFY Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HFY/).

> The story takes place in the near future. After the first alien race to ever make contact with Earth invades the planet and nearly destroys all of human society by *complete accident*, the Galactic Senate decides to uplift humanity as reparations. There are a few reasons why they make this decision - partly out of guilt, partly out of genuine kindness.
>
> Mostly, though? It's because the aliens all think we're *adorable*.

The three extant alien species are larger, stronger, and more advanced than humanity. Thus, we come off as being very small and cute, complicated by some other factors such as how humans smell just like newborn cubs for the wolf-life Dorarizin race, which leads to instinctual cuddling and an urge to defend us. Similarly, the Karnakian race can see souls, and humans have the soul of a hatchling. Besides humans being so small and relatively primitive, the Karnakians are operating on massive guilt due to them nearly destroying human civilization in First Contact. The stories came out starting in 2019, humans are coddled and doted upon rather than every desire granted, and it's not hurting human society, but it matches closely enough that I figured it was worth posting.

Comment: Cheers for this (sarcastic tone!) I'd never heard of They Are Smol until now....I started reading the series last night and got hooked so I couldn't stop reading. Exhausted now after maybe one hours sleep!